# Is a polynomial irreducible modulo a silly large prime

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Suppose I have a large ($\approx 2^{64}$) prime $p$, and a polynomial $g(x)$ of degree $d$ that irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.
If $d << p$, is it likely that $g(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: The size of the prime isn't necessarily relevant.  For example $x^2+1$ is reducible mod($p$) for every $p\equiv 1$ mod ($4$).

Comment: It is easier to make an argument in the other direction, that if $g(x)$ is irreducible in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})[x]$, then it will be irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, provided some details about nonvanishing coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ are covered.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the comment, there are polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ which are irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ yet reducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ for every prime $p$.

To construct such a polynomial, choose a (finite) Galois extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ whose Galois group is not cyclic, and choose an element $\alpha\in K$ such that $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and such that $\alpha$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Then if $f(X)$ is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$, then $f$ is reducible modulo $p$ for every prime $p$. The proof uses local fields and essentially boils down to the fact that Galois groups of extensions of finite fields are always cyclic.

Comment: You might have obliged us with an example!

Comment: $f(X)=X^4-10X^2+1$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$, which generates the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: What you wrote is a much better solution, but it may be worth mentioning that it's not hard to give an elementary proof that $X^4 - 10X^2 + 1$ is reducible at every prime $p$ (by, for example, considering four separate cases $(2/p) = \pm 1, (3/p) = \pm 1$). It's not particularly enlightening, though.

Answer (score 3):

In the other direction, we have for example the Weak Tchebotarev Theorem that says that if $f\in\mathbb Z[X]$ is irreducible and $[K_f:\mathbb Q]=n$, where $K_f$ denotes the splitting field of $f$, then the set $P$ of primes over which $f$ factorizes as a product of linear factors has density $1/n$ in the set of all primes, so in particular it is not bounded. 
If the Galois group of $f$ is abelian, then the set $P$ is in fact characterized by congruences; cyclotomic polynomials provide examples of this.

Notice this is not quite what you asked, as this set $P$ is the set of worst possible primes, while you are considering primes over which the polynomial simply factors.

There is a very nice article on this subject, [Wyman, B. F.. “What Is a Reciprocity Law?”. The American Mathematical Monthly 79.6 (1972): 571–586]